# Bower issue with Grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to work on an angular project for school. I am having a little bit of confusion in the set up problem and I can't find the issue online. I've installed grunt, bower, and yeoman and everything seemed to install but when I ran "grunt serve", the tutorial states I should be able to open local host with a webpage served but the command completes and I'm not sure if it's because of this error that it displays:

"Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages."

Comment: What generator are you using? make sure you have **git** installed and added to your **PATH**, try `bower install` and then execute `grunt serve` again.

Comment: That seemed to be it but I enabled Mongo in the yeoman set up which I guess I shouldn't have, now I'm getting this error "MongoDB connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED" which seems to be keeping the page from displaying